# How to let placeManager.revealPlace open a request in a New Tab, in GWTP?

Tags: url, gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

In GWTP, we can go into new url by:

```
    PlaceRequest request = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.myTok).with("param1","123");
    placeManager.revealPlace(request);
```

However, these above codes will open a new url (ex: abc.com#myTok;param1=123) into the current tab. My question is how to let placeManager to open new url into a new tab?

There is other solution that can be found on internet but I am not sure it is the good one. We can

```
    String url = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder()
    .setHash("myTok;param1="+URL.encodeQueryString("123"))
    .buildString(); 
    Window.open(url, "_blank", null);
```

I think the 2nd solution is not elegant since we have to manually put the param into the url my ourselves, while in the 1st one, all the params was wrapped inside `.with` method.

So How to let placeManager.revealPlace open a request in a New Tab, in GWTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
String url = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash(placeManager.buildHistoryToken(request)).buildString();
Window.open(url, "_blank", null);
```

Comment: u missed .buildString(). Anyway, thank you very much for your answer.